# Stored Procedure Error Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I know this question has been asked so many times. 
But I googled a lot and also went through the answers over here but couldn't able to understand why my stored Procedure is giving this error repeatedly since little while ago the same code was perfectly working fine.

Please any one can help my identify that why this error is coming.
Also Even if when this was working I was not getting my desired output as I want to generate the order numbers in sequence but I'm getting the same number as the number of count.

```
USE [Sost_Dev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [sost].[GetExternalOrderNumbers]
    @Count int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @ExternalOrderNumbers nvarchar(50)

SET @year = RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(yy, GETUTCDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)),2)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
BEGIN TRAN
SAVE TRAN seq

            --Creating Temp Table for every isolated connection
            CREATE TABLE #NewOrders(ExtOrderNumber nvarchar(50));

            WHILE @Count > 0
                BEGIN
                   INSERT INTO [sost].ServiceOrderNumberSequence DEFAULT VALUES
                    SET @ExternalOrderNumbers = 'ESON' + @year + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10) + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS  NVARCHAR(7)) ,7);
                    print 'External' + @ExternalOrderNumbers;
                    --Insert New Order Number to Temporary Tables
                   INSERT INTO #NewOrders  values(@ExternalOrderNumbers)
                   SET @Count -=1
                END

COMMIT

--Fetching Order Numbers from Temporary Table.

SELECT @ExternalOrderNumbers as ExternalOrderNumber from #NewOrders
END
```

Please see the below image for the error in my SQLServer
[image]

[image]

Please find the result All the order numbers are same but I want in consecutive manner.
[image]

Comment: print SCOPE_IDENTITY() result, it might be giving output greater than 7 digits.

Comment: yes correct.. It was giving output of add digits. In that case can you please tell me how to restrict it 7 only

Comment: USE right(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),7) or left(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),7) function according to your need.

Comment: I'm already using right function but still I got this error

Comment: But you are using right after casting, hence you got the error.

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line

```
SET @ExternalOrderNumbers = 'ESON' + @year + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10) + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS  NVARCHAR(100)) ,7);
```

Edit: AS per your requirement.

```
SET @ExternalOrderNumbers = 'ESON' + @year + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10) + CAST(RIGHT(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),7) AS  NVARCHAR(7)) ,7);
```

Comment: Thanks @Atk It solved my error. Can you please address my second problem also. It would be very much help for me.

Comment: run this query and share the output so that i can help you @KarthikSaxena

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Still I'm getting the repeated values like I showed in my edited question

Comment: @KarthikSaxena Share schema of your table [sost].ServiceOrderNumberSequence